# Search for string in values of a dict and return new dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dict

```
{'returnData': [{'eMail': None,
                 'firstName': 'Peter',
                 'id': '1234',
                 'name': 'Parker'},

                {'eMail': 'lucky@mail.example',
                 'firstName': 'Lucky',
                 'id': '123',
                 'name': 'Luke'},

                {'eMail': 'micky@mail.example',
                 'firstName': 'Micky',
                 'id': '3456',
                 'name': 'Mouse'}],
 'status': {'errorCode': 0,
            'message': None,
            'subErrorCode': None,
            'success': True}}
```

How would i search the dict for the values of `eMail`, `firstName` and `name` and return all found matches in a new dict.

For example, i search for `mail.example` it should return only two entries.

Comment: So loop over the dicts and check if the `eMail` value contains `"mail.example"`. You need a loop and an `if`. Where's the problem?

Comment: are you sure looking for `mail.example` should return all three entries? it does not appear in the first entry.

Comment: You are right, i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python3**

*Solution 1:*

```
list(filter(lambda profile: '@mail.example' in str(profile['eMail']), data['returnData']))
```

to search in all values of dict

```
list(filter(lambda profile: '@mail.example' in str(
    profile.items()), data['returnData']))
```

*Solution 2:*

Create a search function.

```
data = {'returnData': [{'eMail': None,
                    'firstName': 'Peter',
                    'id': '1234',
                    'name': 'Parker'},

                   {'eMail': 'lucky@mail.example',
                    'firstName': 'Lucky',
                    'id': '123',
                    'name': 'Luke'},

                   {'eMail': 'micky@mail.example',
                    'firstName': 'Micky',
                    'id': '3456',
                    'name': 'Mouse'}],
    'status': {'errorCode': 0,
               'message': None,
               'subErrorCode': None,
               'success': True}}

def search(search_term, field, data):
    result = []
    for item in data:
        if search_term in str(item[field]):
            result.append(item)

    return result

print(search("@mail.example", "eMail", data['returnData']))
```

Comment: Solution 1 works fine. Is it possible that it does a search in all keys, not only in profile['eMail'] ? Or do i have to run it multiple times for every key i want to search?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. You need change it to profile.items()

Comment: solution1 would be wrong when you search for  any string or substring of 'dict_items'  it returns all profile.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `dict_['returnData']` to look for the `eMail`:

```
dict_ = {'returnData': [{'eMail': None,
                 'firstName': 'Peter',
                 'id': '1234',
                 'name': 'Parker'},

                {'eMail': 'lucky@mail.example',
                 'firstName': 'Lucky',
                 'id': '123',
                 'name': 'Luke'},

                {'eMail': 'micky@mail.example',
                 'firstName': 'Micky',
                 'id': '3456',
                 'name': 'Mouse'}],
 'status': {'errorCode': 0,
            'message': None,
            'subErrorCode': None,
            'success': True}}

for elem in dict_['returnData']:
        print(elem['eMail'])
```

> Note: use `if elem['firstName']: print(elem['eMail'])` for only two
>   enteries

**OUTPUT**:

```
None
lucky@mail.example
micky@mail.example
```

**EDIT**:

even better, using `lists`:

```
firstNames = []
names = []
emails = []

for elem in dict_['returnData']:
    if elem['firstName']:
        firstNames.append(elem['firstName'])
    if elem['name']:
        names.append(elem['name'])
    if elem['eMail']:
        emails.append(elem['eMail'])

print("First Names: {}".format(firstNames))
print("Names: {}".format(names))
print("Emails: {}".format(emails))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
First Names: ['Peter', 'Lucky', 'Micky']
Names: ['Parker', 'Luke', 'Mouse']
Emails: ['lucky@mail.example', 'micky@mail.example']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use re module here

```
import re

d = {'returnData': [{'eMail': None,
                 'firstName': 'Peter',
                 'id': '1234',
                 'name': 'Parker'},

                {'eMail': 'lucky@mail.example',
                 'firstName': 'Lucky',
                 'id': '123',
                 'name': 'Luke'},

                {'eMail': 'micky@mail.example',
                 'firstName': 'Micky',
                 'id': '3456',
                 'name': 'Mouse'}],
 'status': {'errorCode': 0,
            'message': None,
            'subErrorCode': None,
            'success': True}}

out = []
for entry in d['returnData']:
    pattern = 'mail.example'
    email = entry.get('eMail', None)
    if email and re.search(pattern, email):
        out.append(email)
print(out)
```